# Messenger Extensions - FB Shared Link

Tags: javascript, facebook, webview, facebook-messenger, messenger

I have a web page where I have added Messenger Extension for sharing a message to Messenger. I have followed the link as follows.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/sharing/v2.10

The message object I am trying to share is as follows:

```
var messageToShare = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
            "template_type": "generic",
            "elements": [{
                "title": "title text",
                "image_url": "image url",
                "subtitle": "subtitle text",
                "default_action": {
                    "type": "web_url",
                    "url": "url"
                },
                "buttons": [{
                    "type": "web_url",
                    "url": "button url",
                    "title": "button title"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

And the code to share is as follows:

```
$('#share-messenger').click(function () {
    MessengerExtensions.beginShareFlow(function success(response) {
            if (response.is_sent) {
                console.log("Shared in messenger")
            } else {
                console.log("Did not share in messenger")
            }
        }, function error(errorCode, errorMessage) {
            console.log("error in sharing in messenger " + errorCode + ", " +
                errorMessage)
        },
        messageToShare,
        "broadcast");
});
```

I am getting an error as follows in the above error callback when I click on the button.

> Messenger Extensions are not enabled - could be "messenger_extensions"
>   was not set on a url, the domain was not whitelisted or this is an
>   outdated version of Messenger client.

I went through the Troubleshooting guide for this but unable to understand the same. There is a point as follows.

> When you are opening the webview from the persistent menu or a button,
>   ensure that the messenger_extensions parameter is set to true.

which I did't understand.

Can anyone explain me what exactly this error is or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In you `messageToShare` object, you need to set `messenger_extensions: true` on the button to enable the Messenger Extensions SDK in the webview:

```
"buttons": [{
  "type": "web_url",
  "url": "button url",
  "title": "button title",
  "messenger_extension": true
}]
```